# Is anything wrong in following code?

Tags: perl

I am trying to insert multiple values to the same field using a single query. Are there any mistakes in the following code?

```
my $dbh =  DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:accounting:localhost", 'username', 'password',
      {RaiseError => 1});
my @id = [1,18,976,90];
my @name = ['ss','dc','ws','rd'];
my @data = ([@id],[@name]);
my $ab = $dbh->prepare("insert into table (id,name) values (?,?)";);
for my $datam (@data) {
  $ab->execute(@$datam);
}
$ab->finish();
```

I am getting the following error: `DBI::st=HASH(0*a16f774)` for prepare statement. What could be causing this?

Comment: That's not an error message. What do you actually get?

Comment: I don't think your data structure, `@data`, is being created with the structure you think it is. `@data` contains only two entries, both references to arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't really answer your question since you didn't actually give the error, but I have spotted a problem with your code. You're doing

```
$ab->execute([1,18,976,90]);
$ab->execute(['ss','dc','ws','rd']);
```

when you obviously want to do

```
$ab->execute(  1, 'ss');
$ab->execute( 18, 'dc');
$ab->execute(976, 'ws');
$ab->execute( 90, 'rd');
```

Fix:

```
my @id = (1,18,976,90);
my @name = ('ss','dc','ws','rd');

for my $i (0..$#id) {
   $ab->execute($id[$i], $name[$i]);
}
```

Comment: No, there's no variable `$id`, so that's obviously wrong. `$#id`, on the other hand, means the last index of the array `@id`, which is exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 3):

I notice that your structure:

```
my @id = [1, 18, 976, 90];
```

is array with one element, which is array reference. You can check structure of variable by module `Data::Dumper`. So you need only simple array:

```
my @id = (1, 18, 976, 90);
```

**Using Data::Dumper**

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper( \@id );

$VAR1 = [
      [
        1,
        18,
        976,
        90
      ]
    ];
```

**Solution**

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(each_array);

my @id   = (1, 18, 976, 90);
my @name = ('ss', 'dc', 'ws', 'rd');

my $data = each_array(@id, @name);

...
while (my ($id, $name) = $data->()) {

    $ab->execute($id, $name);
}
```